# How to find objects where the key is NOT in a StringListProperty in GoogleAppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm pretty sure the above is NOT directly possible (but I would be happy to be wrong).  So here is what I am trying to do, but I can't figure out how to do get a useful query to work.

```
class Challenge(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    players = db.StringListProperty(default=[])
    created_on = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    completed_on = db.DateTimeProperty(default=None)
```

There can be thousands of challenges.  You can join *any number of* challenges at any time (prior to it being 'completed', but you can only join any challenge one time.

*edit-----------------------------*

**Challenges are completed asynchronously (they can last multiple days) and a "winner" is decided at the end of that period, so people might be in several challenges at the same time, waiting for those challenges to end.  Basically, you join a challenge and complete the task, then wait for others to do the same, then the winner is chosen when the challenge comes to a end.  While you are waiting, you can join and complete other challenges.  There is a limit of 250-500 people per challenge (haven't decided on the max yet)**

*------------------------------edit*

I want to make a list of all the challenges you CAN join, ordered by `created_on`.  `players` is a list of `str(user.key())` for all those that have joined a challenge.

You could do it something like:

```
already_in = Challenge.all().filter('players = ', str(self.user.key())).filter('completed_on =', None)
already_in_set = set()    
for challenge in already_in.fetch(1000):
    already_in_set.add(str(challenge.key()))  # Could cache this in the user object

challenges = Challenge.all().order('created_on')
keepers = []
for challenge in challenges:
    if str(challenge.key()) not in already_in_set:
        keepers.append(challenge)
        if len(keepers) > 11:
            break
```

and now `keepers` has the list of the ones you aren't in.  But the above code doesn't feel very optimal.

Surely there is another way to do this.  (I'm not against restructuring the db to make it work better either)

I could cache the already_in_set as a `StringListPropery(indexed=False)` on the `User` object and that would provide some speed up, but then I'd have to prune that to remove Challenges that are now completed (which I could do outside the UI request).

I'm hoping I'm missing something obvious about how to use the AppEngine datastore to do the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you guessed, this isn't really possible. Elements in list properties are indexed individually, so a filter for "not equal to x" would return any list that has at least one value not equal to x, not the desired result.

Given the situation you describe, though, it seems unlikely that users will be in an unbounded number of challenges. Fetching the challenges they're already in, and filtering those results out of result sets, seems like a reasonable solution. If you want to make things more efficient, you could store the list of challenges against the user instead of vice-versa. This also means there's no longer a practical limit on how many users can participate in a given challenge.

Finally, don't use a `db.StringListProperty` to store serialized keys - instead, use a `db.ListProperty(db.Key)`.

Answer (score 0):

Given the constraint that a user can only join one challenge at a time, if you record the non-completed challenge (if any) that a user is participating in, you can retrieve that very efficiently. Then (if I understand you correctly) one of two cases apply: Either the user is participating in a Challenge already, in which case no query on Challenge is needed, or you do need to query for available challenges. To do the latter query, it might help to also store a `completed` flag in the Challenge.

This means you'll have to do a bit of additional bookkeeping when a Challenge is completed, finding all participating Users and voiding their participation.

Comment: I edited the description to indicate you can be in multiple concurrent challenges.  And the # of people in that challenge with you could be large.  Sorry I failed to state that initially.